# WPF Temp PlaceHolder For 3rd Party Control loading to long

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a UI taking a long time because of a intensive 3rd Party Control on this View.

So I am trying to solve it by having a Temp Grid when a property of IsStillLoading = true

When IsStillLoading = false the grid gets replaced by the 3rd Party Control

I do this by using DataTemplates

```
<Style x:Key="ViewLoadingHelper" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDataLoading}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="DummyBeforeLoad" Background="LightGray" >

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDataLoading}" Value="false">

            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <myThirdPartyControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Grid>
     <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ViewLoadingHelper}"/>
</Grid>
```

I have 2 questions:
1) Is this the correct approach? Or would you do it differently?
2) Where can I get or what is this blurry placeholder called.
I am currently using a gray grid, but for example when you look at Facebook, hit the refresh on your browser. For a brieve moment you will see a list of dummy/placeholders posts before seeing the real posts. This is the idea I have and whant to implement this.

Comment: You could have 2 separate controls and bind to their visibility property so when one is visible the other is hidden

Comment: The problem with this is that the 3rd Party Control's bindings will still bind unnessasary. Part of the reason why the 3rd party control is taking so long is because of all the bindings that needs to be set on the control.